# How to include jdk.attach module using Bazel, building with JDK 11 but targeting Java 1.8?

Tags: java, jmx, bazel, java-11

I'm working on a component which uses the Java Attach API (package `com.sun.tools.attach`, module `jdk.attach`) to extract JMX metrics from another long-running task. We use Bazel as our build framework, which should be taking all platform variances out of the equation. But while I am able to build the project locally, it fails when built on the CI server.

The situation is further complicated by the fact that we're building using JDK 11, targeting Java 1.8. In Java 1.8, this API is in `tools.jar`, which is in `$JAVA_HOME/lib`, but in Java 11 it is in the `jdk.attach` module, which is presumably in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/libattach.so`. But when I attempt to add module loading flags (eg `--add-opens`) using the `javacopts` parameter I get an error.

This is the build rule:

```
java_binary(
    name = "dbz-liveness",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    main_class = "...",
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**/*.properties"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:ch_qos_logback_logback_classic",
        "@maven//:ch_qos_logback_logback_core",
        "@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_api",
    ],
)
```

Here's the JMX code that won't compile:

```
package com.qfree.cdc.liveness;

import com.sun.tools.attach.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;
import javax.management.openmbean.TabularData;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A wrapper to establish a JMX connection to a named job, even if that job
 * wasn't launched with JMX enabled.
 */
public class JMXProbe implements AutoCloseable {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMXProbe.class);
  private static final String CONNECTOR_ADDRESS =
      "com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress";

  private final Pattern jobPattern;
  private JMXConnector connector;

  /**
   *
   * @param pattern A regex specifying the name of the job to connect to
   */
  public JMXProbe(String pattern) {
    jobPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  }

  /**
   * Locate the specified Java task, and open a JMX connection to it
   *
   * @throws IOException if connection to the named JVM fails (may wrap other nested
   *      exception types)
   *
   * @return {@code true} if the named JVM is found and the JMX connection is established
   */
  public boolean open() throws IOException {
    List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> list = VirtualMachine.list();

    for (VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd: list) {
      if (jobPattern.matcher(vmd.displayName()).find()) {
        try {
          log.debug("Found {}; attempting to connect to JMX...", vmd.displayName());
          openConnection(vmd);
        } catch (AttachNotSupportedException | AgentLoadException | AgentInitializationException e) {
          throw new IOException(String.format("Cannot connect to JVM %s", vmd.displayName()), e);
        }
        log.debug("Successfully connected to JMX agent");
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  private void openConnection(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
    // attach to the target application
    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd);

    // get the connector address
    String connectorAddress =
        vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty(CONNECTOR_ADDRESS);

    // no connector address, so we start the JMX agent
    if (connectorAddress == null) {
      log.debug("Attempting to start JMX agent");
      String agent = vm.getSystemProperties().getProperty("java.home") +
          File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "management-agent.jar";
      vm.loadAgent(agent);

      // agent is started, get the connector address
      connectorAddress =
          vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty(CONNECTOR_ADDRESS);
    }

    log.debug("Connecting to {}", connectorAddress);

    // establish connection to connector server
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress);
    connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
  }

  public JMXConnector getConnector() {
    return connector;
  }
}
```

And here are the errors I'm getting:

```
services/storage/cdc/liveness/src/main/java/com/qfree/cdc/liveness/JMXProbe.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  private void openConnection(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
                              ^
  symbol:   class VirtualMachineDescriptor
  location: class JMXProbe
services/storage/cdc/liveness/src/main/java/com/qfree/cdc/liveness/JMXProbe.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  private void openConnection(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class AttachNotSupportedException
  location: class JMXProbe
services/storage/cdc/liveness/src/main/java/com/qfree/cdc/liveness/JMXProbe.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  private void openConnection(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
                                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   class AgentLoadException
  location: class JMXProbe
services/storage/cdc/liveness/src/main/java/com/qfree/cdc/liveness/JMXProbe.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  private void openConnection(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
                                                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class AgentInitializationException
  location: class JMXProbe
services/storage/cdc/liveness/src/main/java/com/qfree/cdc/liveness/JMXProbe.java:3: error: package com.sun.tools.attach does not exist
import com.sun.tools.attach.*;
^
```

So how do I untangle this?

Comment: There is no point in specifying `--add-opens`. But anyway, I don’t see any of the described options (“using JDK 11, targeting Java 1.8”) in that configuration.

Comment: Toolchain and language level are set in the root BUILD.bazel for the project. The point being that I can't add the module, because I'm targeting a non module-aware version of the JRE. But I can't specify the JAR because it's not available as part of JDK11.

And I can't figure out how this is working when I run Bazel build on my local machine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Maven. Did you figure out a way to do that?